# Google script: Cannot call method of null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am using the google script for calendar and just try to play with their example. But when i run the code below , it keep saying cannot call method”createEvent” of null. Actually I am not quite understand the callback function here. So it's either a general js question or a google script question.

```
  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
      description : desc,
      location : loc
  });
};
```

Here is the whole code:

```
function createEvent() {
  /*var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);*/
  var cal = CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars()[0];
  var title = 'Script Demo Event';
  var start = new Date("October 26, 2013 08:00:00 EST");
  var end = new Date("October 26, 2013 10:00:00 EST");
  var desc = 'Created using Google Apps Script';
  var loc = 'Script Center';


  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
      description : desc,
      location : loc
  });
};



function doGet() { // A script with a user interface that is published as a web app
  // must contain a doGet(e) function.

  // Create the UiInstance object myapp and set the title text
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Here is the title bar');

  // Create a button called mybutton and set the button text
  var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Here is a button');
  var handler = myapp.createServerHandler('createEventInvitePeople');
  mybutton.addClickHandler(handler);

  // Create a vertical panel called mypanel and add it to myapp
  var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();

  // Add mybutton to mypanel
  mypanel.add(mybutton);

  // Add my panel to myapp
  myapp.add(mypanel);

  // return myapp to display the UiInstance object and all elements associated with it.
  return myapp;

}


/**
 * Creates an event, invite guests, book rooms, and sends invitation emails.
 * For more information on using Calendar events, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendarevent.
 */
function createEventInvitePeople() {
  var calId = CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars()[0];
  var room1CalId = 'a_room_cal_id';
  var room2CalId = 'another_room_cal_id';
  var guest1Email = 'XXX@gmail.com';
  var guest2Email = 'XXX@gmail.com';
  var invitees = room1CalId + ',' + room2CalId + ',' + guest1Email + ',' +
      guest2Email;

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  var title = 'Script Center Demo Event';
  var start = new Date("October 30, 2012 08:00:00 PDT");
  var end = new Date("October 30, 2012 10:00:00 PDT");
  var desc = 'Created using Apps Script';
  var loc = 'Script Center';
  var send = 'true';

  var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
      description : desc,
      location : loc,
      guests : invitees,
      sendInvites : send
  });
};
```

can anyone do me a favor?

Comment: Could you explain how you deployed your app, when does the error occur, what example you refer to?

Comment: I use the code i show above. and I run the function doGet() and deploy it as an app.

Comment: Have you read this explanation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps? Once you've selected the options you want to use for your web app, click the Deploy button. You'll see a new dialog with a message indicating that your project has been successfully deployed as a web app. Below that message you'll find the URL of your web app. Copy that URL and use it to access your web app in a browser.

Comment: Yeah I have deployed this app and there is a webpage with a button, but when i click it, alert shows"cannot call method"createEvent" of null

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is because the getAllOwnedCalendars() is not returning any calendars, and you're assuming it is.  So you're using [0] at the beginning to get the first one off the list, but its not valid.  If you're running this from the web, you may have to be more specific in finding the calendar you want.